# MATLAB - Unrolled loop on the last two iteration is slower than the full iterations

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

I have to optimize this algorithm calculated over an triadiagonal matrix H.

```
Q(:,n+1) = A*Q(:,n);
    
for j = 1:n
    H(j,n) = Q(:,j)'*Q(:,n+1);
    Q(:,n+1) = Q(:,n+1) - H(j,n)*Q(:,j);
end

H(n+1,n) = norm(Q(:,n+1));
Q(:,n+1) = Q(:,n+1)/norm(Q(:,n+1));
```

Starting from n>3, all the values between H(1,n)...H(n-2,n) are zeros (since it is tridiagonal); for this reason, I would optimize the for skipping all these iterations, in this (naive) way:

```
if n>3
     for j = (n-1):n 
         H(j,n) = Q(:,j)'*tmp;
         tmp = tmp - H(j,n)*Q(:,j);
     end
else
     for j = 1:n 
         H(j,n) = Q(:,j)'*tmp;
         tmp = tmp - H(j,n)*Q(:,j);
      end
end
```

This algorithm skips all the zeros but the problem is that the whole algorithm is slower than the previous one. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], otherwise we cannot test and profile this to suggest improvements

Comment: It is hard to run your code if we don't know what `A` and `Q` and `H` and `n` are. If we can't run your code, we cannot reproduce your problem and play with it, which means we cannot try to figure out why the one is slower than the other. Are any of these matrices growing inside the loop?

Comment: I am sorry, just added the Matlab code into the question

Comment: Please read [mre]. You need to include everything important to the question into the post itself, outside links can die, making the question useless. Shorten your code so it is as short as possible but still shows the problem, then add it into your post.

Comment: You initialize `H = []`, this is a really bad idea, it will slow your code down significantly. If you know what sizes it will have, allocate the array of the appropriate size. Otherwise allocate an array that is larger than what you'll need, and trim after the loops. Also, the two functions you're timing have many other differences besides the loop you show here -- any of those could be the culprit. This is why a [mre] is important: removing bits of code will show you exactly which bits of code cause the slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Now, that there's the code available, I can give some more tips.

First one: Use the built in Code Analyzer:
[image]
You can see that there are multiple unused variables, one potentially uninitialized variable and lots of variables that change sizes on every loop iteration.

I commented the uninitialized variable `H_buono` since it leads to errors otherwise and it's used for printing the difference only.

Especially the latter has significant speed impact because the arrays have to be grown every couple loop iterations. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html

Running the script creates

[image]

which shows that `GMRES_givens_lanczos` needs 86 iterations more than `GMRES_givens` for worse error. I won't go into detail of the algorithm, but we can gain some speed.

First, look at the profiler:
[image]
`GMRES_givens_lanczos` needs 65% of the computation time, `GMRES_givens` only 24%. Let's figure out why.

[image]
The two most important lines are solving the linear system (line 84) and some allocations in line 73.
`H(i:i+1,n) = Q_Givens_list{i}'*H(i:i+1,n);` even uses a cell array (`{}`) which slows down things, too.

The simplest tip is to pre-allocate `H`:
    `H = zeros(max_iteration+1,max_iteration);`, but if that's helpful depends on `max_iterations` and your memory.

Lines to adapt:
`Q_Givens = Givens_QR(H(:,n), n, n+1);`
->`Q_Givens = Givens_QR(H(1:n+1,n), n, n+1);`
`y = H\e;` -> `y = H(1:n+1,1:n)\e;`

BUT: given the fact, that solving the equation system via `y = H\e;` already takes more time than
`GMRES_givens` I'd assume there's an error in `GMRES_givens_lanczos`.

Set `max_iteration = 100` to have the same amount of iterations as `GMRES_givens` needs (your 5050 iterations are not correct imo) and see that with preallocation `GMRES_givens_lanczos` now is slightly faster. But the error is much higher. I think, there's an error in your algorithm.

[image]

General tip:

- Don't use `i` or `j` as loop indices, since it's the imaginary unit in `z=a+jb`. I recommend `k,m,n` for *very* short loops and names like `nRow`, `colIdx`, or `iCol`, or `kRow` etc.

OLD:

Do you have a minimal working example? The code can't run. Then, have a look at the Matlab profiler and check the timings.

Could be due to cache misses or the JIT compiler can't compile your second version? See also https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/performance.html

Comment: Thank you! But if the original code works, in your opinion what could be the error?

Comment: @JeremyCaney there's no code I could copy. It's a screenshot of the code anaysis tool and imo that's perfectly right as an image. I'm using the original code of the TE.

Comment: @GiorgioMartinez I don't know what the error is. Your optimized version needs more iterations and has a higher error, so clearly there's something different. Indeed, your modifications made the code a bit faster (combined with my recommendations). I don't know the algorithm - maybe your assumption of tridiagonal is not 100% correct?